# Change the background colour of a Raphael "Label"

Tags: javascript, raphael, graphael

If I create a [`Label`](http://g.raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.label) using Raphael, the default style is a black block with white text.

How can I change the background box colour, but not the text colour? I've tried:

```
paper.label(x, y, value).attr("fill", colour)
```

but that also fills the text and I end up with invisible text.

I also can't simply change the default colour in [this function](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael/blob/master/g.raphael.js#L328) because I need to have a few different ones depending on a line that it's added to:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you noticed,

```
Paper.label(x, y, value).attr(
    fill : color
);
```

changes both the background fill color and the text fill color, resulting in invisible text.

Unspecified correctly explained that this is an array, so each portion must be altered separately, as they illustrated.  However, they didn't mention the easiest way to change update both sets of attributes, so I wanted to share this tip.  In order to do this, change the attributes into an array with two sets.  The first element is the background, and the second is the text.

```
Paper.label(x, y, value).attr([{
    fill : backgroundColor
}, {
    fill : textColor
}]);
```

You can add any other applicable attributes to each part.  Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/VzpeG/1/

Comment: Thanks, I think this more accurately answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a graph similar to this and used:

> .attr({fill: "#EF7C4D"})

Let me know how this goes...

Comment: Thanks Rob, although I mentioned that I've tried this and found it also filled the text. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
var r = Raphael('divID', 320, 220);
text = r.text(100,100,"Hello").attr({fill:"#fff"});​​​​
text.label().attr({fill:"#f00"});
```

Here's a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vpGyL/216/

Set any color on text or on label both apply separately...Hope this helps !

Digging in furthur...`Paper.label(x,y,text)` is different from `Element.label()`

If you look at the source code `Paper.Label(x,y,text)` is a set of rectangle element & text element, so doing `.attr({fill:"SomeColor"})` applies to the entire set, hence both rectangle & text share same color(Hence the invisibility).

Oh yeah If you just want to change the text color do this `Raphael.g.txtattr.fill = "#yourColorCode"` But this changes the text color globally on all the charts and tooltips(don't seem to be a good idea).

While `Element.Label` as the documentation says is takes the context element & embed in a label tooltip, basically whatever `element` you use, applying `.label` will embed it inside a rectangle